# Units of energy and frequency

Tags: atomic-physics, units, laser-interaction

I read a paper about using femtosecond laser to process an atom. The units used in the paper bothered me. I have four questions.

(1) Why the unit of energy is cm$^{-1}$?
[image]

(2) It seems that the author take the reduced Planck constant to be one. Then what is the meaning of $\omega$? Is it frequency or angular velocity? Why is its unit also cm$^{-1}$?
[image]

(3) Why the unit of the dipole operator arbitrary? How to use this operator?
[image]

(4) If the unit of $\omega$ is cm$^{-1}$, why is the unit of its inverse fs? If $\omega_0$ is to be multiplied with time, its unit should be s$^{-1}$. How can it be cm$^{-1}$?
[image]

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber#Definition for example

Comment: @JonCuster In the second image of my post, $\Delta\omega$=177 cm$^{−1}$. In the last image of my post, $1/\Delta\omega$=30 fs. I understand the unit is fs. But I don't understand why the number is 30. Can you explain why?

Answer (score 0):

In "natural units" we take c (speed of light) = 1, hence time and spatial measures are the same. Also, reduced Planck constant is taken as 1, and energy measures equal inverse time measures(i.e., frequency). Combining them, you see that inverse length can be a perfectly reasonable energy measure.

It makes sense for the same reason that if you were a thinking fly, miliinches rather than inches would be a better day-to-day standard scale

Comment: I wouldn't say that scaling units up and down with prefixes is the same as changing to a new unit system.

Comment: I just said it makes sense for the same reason since e.g. in high energy physics we would constantly use superfluous c in computations of energy whereas a simple mass can be used to define It satisfactorily... Is it clear now?

Comment: It is natural in the same sense as it is natural for flies to think their world in miliscale. Their international scale system would probably set it as their standard. And so, setting c = 1 is a natural standard for high-energy physicists to think their physics world...

Comment: In the second image of my post, $\Delta\omega=177$ cm$^{-1}$. In the last image of my post, $1/\Delta\omega=30$ fs. I understand the unit is fs. But I don't understand why the number is 30. Can you explain why?